# ITextSharp performance of nested tables

Tags: c#, itext

for my project I need to draw some generic controls to a PDF document. 
The controls I'm converting can have childcontrols. Sometimes, they can go as deep as 12 levels of recursion. 
To reflect this behaviour in PDF, I chose the PdfPTable class as the base class for my controls, because they can have childcontrols (Cells).

It all works well, but becomes terribly slow when the recursive depth increases. Here comes the code I used in my performance test:

```
private const int MaxDepth = 12;
    private static void NestTable(PdfPCell cell, int level)
    {
        //check max depth
        if (level == MaxDepth)
        {
            return;
        }

        //create new table with one column
        var table = new PdfPTable(1);

        //Display the current depth in the cell
        var mainCell = new PdfPCell { Phrase = new Phrase(level) };

        //recursion here:
        NestTable(mainCell, level + 1);

        //add the cell to the control tree
        table.AddCell(mainCell);

        //add table to the parent cell
        cell.AddElement(table);
    }
```

And here is a fragment of the times I measured to create a table with this code, and then call `document.Add(table)` for different values of *MaxDepth*:

```
7: 91 ms
8: 168ms
9: 356ms
10: 920ms
11: 978ms
12: 2757ms
13: 8358ms
14: 25449ms
```

These times seem unacceptable to me.
Does anyone have any idea how to improve the performance of nested tables? 
Or should I avoid tables (PdfPTable) and use another class that has the same output?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Nesting 12 levels down in a table should be unacceptable in any design.

Comment: I don't agree. An html document can go hundreds of levels down and can still be interpreted and rendered extremely fast.

Comment: The last time I checked PDF wasn't HTML. You are comparing apples with oranges. That is not fair.

Comment: That's true, but my point is: what if you want to convert something similar to HTML to PDF? You're going to need (very deep) nesting at some point. How can I do this?

Comment: Absolute positioning and lots of calculations to get the correct positioning. In HTML, you can expand the width endlessly. In PDF, you have a fixed width (and a fixed height per page). How are you going to fit everything inside the dimensions of the page? By using Math...

Comment: That's too bad. I thought iText was the abstraction layer designed to take care of all this.

Comment: It is, but you claim that you can do the Math faster than iText. If that claim is true, then iText has all the tools to allow you to do so. If `PdfPTable` is too slow, you can write your own implementation of a nested structure that is faster.

Comment: I have all width, height and positioning information already available and applied to the cells in my (real) code. Therefore I thought that iText doesn't really have lots of calculations to do. I'm definitly not claiming to calculate stuff faster than iText.. 

I'm still just looking for the best way to tackly my problem. I guess I'll have to draw everything to the canvas by myself without using the helper classes for tables and cells, and that's too bad because it's going to be a time consuming task :)

Comment: In essence iText's table layouting is not designed for such use cases. Mainly the table classes are meant for actual *tables*, not as a generic layout managing containers.

Comment: If you have all the widths and heights already available, than it is much better to add the content at absolute positions using that information.

Comment: Just to throw my two cents in and reiterate what bruno and mkl are saying (and I think the OP knows this, too) **PDFs do not support tables**. The abstraction classes that iText offers for tables are intended to give you helpers to draw tabular data on to a screen. You say "I want two rows and two columns" and iText does the math, draw boxes, applies margins, padding, headers and footers, wraps text and even breaks the table into multiple pages if necessary. If you know all of this information beforehand, however, you can just skip the table and do it on your own.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. I'm rewriting everything to avoid deeply nested tables. It's a lot faster now.